# Don want to use safe remove EX HDD in MAC OS...

Tags: macos, mac, external-hard-drive, safely-remove-hardware

I am using iMac with OS 10.6.8. Every time when I eject my External HDD I have to eject from finder. I want to use like Plug n Play just like in windows no need to give safe remove. If there is any way to do so please let me know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows you are supposed to use the "Safely Eject" option as there could be data still being transferred and could potentially corrupt the data/disk but windows doesn't give you a popup or moan at you if you just pull out the USB.

The Mac on the other-hand likes to alert you if you unplug a USB stick as there could be something accessing it in the background (ie: if you were working on a word doc and didnt close the app down) it could corrupt the file and or the disk.

Ejecting the device on a Mac will also let you know if it is being used by another app etc

hope that helps